# The child view fit-content ， the superview sets the scroll properties

Tags: javascript, css

The child view fit-content exceeds the parent view width, When the superview sets the scroll properties，The subview displays exceptions。
I want to superview Can scroll display, cut does not affect the subview display。

The child view fit-content exceeds the parent view width, When the superview sets the scroll properties，The subview displays exceptions。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .main-container {
        width: 300px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .title {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .tab-contenter {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px 40px 10px 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      .tab-contenter-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        /* overflow: scroll; */
      }
      .tab-title-item {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: fit-content;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 0 11px;
        background: #f5f6f7;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="title">标题</div>
      <div class="tab-contenter">
        <div class="tab-contenter-content">
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi1">
            全部
          </div>
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi2">
            测试内容超长版本2
          </div>
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi3">
            测试内容超长版本3
          </div>
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi4">
            测试内容4
          </div>
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi5">
            测试内容5
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Online code ： https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-raman-wylhk?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
You have to set flex nowrap to the parent. I have added a class to disable the default browser scrollbar as well

```css
.main-container {
        width: 300px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .horizontal-scrollbars {
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }

      .horizontal-scrollbars::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
      }
  
      .title {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .tab-contenter {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px 40px 10px 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      .tab-contenter-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        /* overflow: scroll; */
      }
      .tab-title-item {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        /* padding: 15px; */
        /* height: 100%; */
        width: fit-content;
        white-space: nowrap;
        /* min-width: 53px; */
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 0 11px;
        /* border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; */
        background: #f5f6f7;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
      <div class="title">标题</div>
      <div class="tab-contenter">
        <div class="tab-contenter-content horizontal-scrollbars">
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi1">
            全部
          </div>
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi2">
            测试内容超长版本2
          </div>
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi3">
            测试内容超长版本3
          </div>
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi4">
            测试内容4
          </div>
          <div class="tab-title-item" key="ceshi5">
            测试内容5
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```